# Como alinear verticalemente elementos dentro un li html

Tags: html, css

Tengo una lista, y necesito que los elementos que estan dentro de la etiqueta "li" queden verticalmente, así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi lista esta actualmente así: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta el codigo de mi lista :

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Número del pedido:<strong>15416</strong></li>
  <span class="separador">| </span>
  <li>Fecha:<strong>24 noviembre, 2022</strong></li>
  <span class="separador">| </span>
  <li>Total:<strong><span><bdi><span>&#x20a1;</span>40,937.00</bdi></span></strong></li>
  <span class="separador">| </span>
  <li>Método de pago:<strong>Transferencia bancaria directa</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ponle un <br> después de cada titulillo, así:  `<li>Fecha:<br><strong>`

Comment: Ya intente lo del br y no funciona ya que baja todos elementos consecuentes, incluidos los siguientes li

Comment: Gracias por la aceptación de la respuesta, aún así espera a ver la de @Carlos (si es que la acaba poniendo), pues eso del `display: flex` es algo que no domino y quizás te puede servir mejor que mi respuesta, pues creo que tiene razón y algo se puede hacer con eso.

Comment: Probaste definir cada li como display flex? crear dentro de cada li, 4 divs con un lenght de 20 a 24% y justify-content space evenly?

Comment: @Carlos Tu comentario me parece interesante... ¿porque no lo aportas como respuesta con un ejemplo de como quedaría?  Yo creo que vas bien encaminado (yo no dominio el flex aún) y mi única duda seria como pondrias la barra de separación después, pero supongo que con CSS lo podrás hacer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con un **li** lo veo complicado, pero esta respuesta se basa en una tabla, a ver si te convence:

```css
td {
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Número del pedido:<br><strong>15416</strong></td>

    <td>Fecha:<br><strong>24 noviembre, 2022</strong></td>

    <td>Total:<br><strong><span><bdi><span>&#x20a1;</span>40,937.00</bdi></span></strong></td>

    <td>Método de pago:<br><strong>Transferencia bancaria directa</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Acá armé algo rapido, definiendo cada **li** como `display:flex` y creando un `<div>` dentro de cada *li*, y con `justify-content: space-evenly`,  a ver que te parece:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .datos {
      height: 80%;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    .datos li {
      padding-left: 5%;
      text-align: left;
      border-left: dashed darkgrey 1px;
    }
    
    .datos li:first-child {
      border-left: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="datos">
    <li>
      <div>Número del pedido:<br><strong>15416</strong></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Fecha:<br><strong>24 noviembre, 2022</strong></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Total:<br><strong><span><bdi><span>&#x20a1;</span>40,937.00</bdi></span></strong></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>Método de pago:<br><strong>Transferencia bancaria directa</strong></div>
    </li>

  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Me he tomado la libertad de poner tu código en un snippet para que lo pueda ejecutar aquí mismo y he agregado tu explicación de tu comentario para que la respuesta no sea tan solo de código sin más. Gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser así, dando un **br** al finalizar el titulo del concepto, y una alineación a la izquierda.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  /*espacio entre li de 10 pixeles*/
  padding:10px;
  /*alineacion a la izquierda*/
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Número del pedido: <span class="separador">| </span><br><strong>15416</strong></li>

  <li>Fecha: <span class="separador">| </span><br><strong>24 noviembre, 2022</strong></li>

  <li>Total: <span class="separador">| </span><br><strong><span><bdi><span>&#x20a1;</span>40,937.00</bdi></span></strong></li>

  <li>Método de pago:<br><strong>Transferencia bancaria directa</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Ejecútalo en tu navegador para que lo aprecies bien, dime si te sirvió.